# playing system sounds in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am trying to understand how to play those sounds in iOS. I did found a few code snippets but they dont play anything when I use it. What am I doing wrong?

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices

```
- (IBAction) playSystemSound: (id) sender {

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (1100);
}
```

Comment: How do you know `1100` is an actual, valid, existent system sound ID?

Comment: check the list, it shows up there.

Comment: Make sure you `#import "AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using valid soundID and playing the sound on device then the code you have presented should work.

Alternatively you can use the following code to play the custom sound or audio file if it helps you

```
- (IBAction) playSystemSound: (id) sender {
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"mp3"];
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
}
```

[Apple has provided sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SysSound/Listings/Classes_SysSoundViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008018-Classes_SysSoundViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) for playing sounds you could check that out also.

Comment: not sure i understand where those sound fit in: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices

Comment: the sample code doesnt help since i cant switch tones. it plays only one tone. check it out already.

Comment: @moshikafya the code you have presented should also work if you have valid soundID and you playing on the `Device` not on the `Simulator`, just tested myself